# AWS Secrets manager accessible from EC2 instance but throws NoCredentialsError when running from the docker container deployed on the same instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, boto3

My Python application is deployed in a docker container on an EC2 instance. Passwords are stored in secrets manager. During runtime, application will make an API call to secrets manager to fetch the password and connect. Since we recreated the instance, it started giving out below error -

botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

My application code is -

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client(service_name = 'secretmanager', region_name = 'us-east-1')
get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(secretId = secret_name)
```

If I run -

`aws secretmanager get-secret-value --secret-id abc`

It works without any issues since IAM policy is appropriately attached to the EC2 instance.

I spent the last 2 days trying to troubleshoot this but am still stuck with no clarity on why this is breaking. Any tips or guidance would help.

Comment: Your containers don't have access to instance profile.

Comment: @Marcin - Can you share some document or a link about sharing the instance profile with the containers?

Comment: Can you spin up a test ubuntu container and instal aws cli on it to check if the issue is your one specific container or every container ? Usually the container will automatically "inherit" credentials from the instance metadata.

Comment: its on all containers on the EC2 instance. Additionally, this is an intermittent issue. It works in MODEL and PROD but somehow started breaking in dev and test when we recreated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the HTTPToken variable in the instance metadata options which was defaulted to required with the fresh update. Reverted it back to optional and boto3 is now able to make an API call for instance meta data and inherit its roles.